# Find the index of an array element without using built in indexOf function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am fairly new to JS and have a project to find the index of an array element, without using indexOf built in function. I have tried to search for solutions, but all I get are examples of the aforementioned built in function, which I already know how to use. Can anyone provide a simple example for me to go on? 
My mind goes towards something like this, but please note I am new to this and it is an academic exercise that I really want to understand:

```
var index;
var target = 10;
for(var val in collection){
   if(collection[val] === target){
      index = val;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Loop through the array until you find the value then return index...

Comment: your own attempt looks good except that you need to move "return index;" to the last line - outside of the loop.

Comment: Your return is in the wrong place, you want it after your for loop

Comment: His return is fine it can be in the loop he just needs to move it in the `if` statement.

Comment: If `collection` is actually an array, don't use `for...in`, use a regular loop `for (var i =0; i < collection.length; i++)`. Then in the body of your loop check if `collection[i] == target` and if so return `i`.

Comment: What if the collection is an array of objects? The comparison `collection[val] === target` won't work anymore, you'll have to define a recursive function that checks the equality of the properties for both objects `collection[val]` and `target`

Comment: Your example looks like it should be a function (it has a return statement).  but you don't have the actual function statement.   In this, you're explicitly setting the 'target' value to 10, but I'm assuming the 'collection' value is coming in as a parameter to the function.   Any reason not to have target as an argument as well as collection?

Comment: @MugiwaraUK isn't that exactly what i said why repeat it?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, it is much appreciated. One consistent comment seems to be my use of for-in rather than the usual for loop. I decided on to cater to a collection of array or object. Is my thinking a bit mad here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This attempt is almost correct. You seem to already understand of what is required: loop over the elements of the array until you find a match, and then return the index of that match.

You've made a few mistakes, though. Let's walk through some improvements, step by step.

- Your `return` statement is inside the loop, but outside of the `if`. You only want to `return` if you're found a match. Currently, you always return after the first iteration of the loop!

  ```
  function myIndexOf(collection, target) {
      var index;
      for(var val in collection){
         if(collection[val] === target){
            index = val;
            return index;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- There is no need for a separate `index` variable. You can return `val` as soon as you determine it's the correct answer.

  ```
  function myIndexOf(collection, target) {
      for(var val in collection){
         if(collection[val] === target){
            return val;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- You should loop using a numeric `for` loop, not a `for-in` loop. `for-in` loops are not guaranteed to have a set order, so you may not always get the lowest index that is a match. (Also, `for-in` could match on non-numeric property names, which might not be what you want.)

  ```
  function myIndexOf(collection, target) {
      for(var val=0; val<collection.length; val++){
         if(collection[val] === target){
            return val;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- To act just like `indexOf`, you could return `-1` in the case that you don't find a match.

  ```
  function myIndexOf(collection, target) {
      for(var val=0; val<collection.length; val++){
         if(collection[val] === target){
            return val;
          }
      }
      return -1;
  }
  ```

Comment: What about target is a word.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the
>   index order is important.

[for..in - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
var find_index = function(collection, item) {
   for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; ++i) {
       if (collection[i] === item) {
           return i;
       }
   }
};
find_index([5,4,3,2,1], 5)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation since the OP is new to javascript. +1 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

When looping through an array you should use a simple `for` loop from index `0` to `Length-1` of your array. Don't use `for...in` because it can iterate properties of the array that aren't the actual contents of the cells and the order is not guaranteed. You want to find the *first* match to have the same behavior as `.indexOf`. So the correct implementation would look something like this:

```
function myIndexOf(array, target) {
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === target) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    // item was not found
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in statement to iterate an array, assumings keys are values. Here val will be 0, 1, 2... so you can return it.

Then, you can use the return inside the if : it will stop the function and return the value just right you find what you are loonking for.

The === is the strict comparaison operator, checking  var type, allowing you to test this is the exact value you are looking for.

You can add a return with an other value (here -1) if the value is not found at the end of the loop.

```
function myIndexOf(array, search) {
    for(var val in array){
       if(array[val] === search){
            return val;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(myIndexOf(myArray, 'c')); //2
console.log(myIndexOf(myArray, 'f')); //-1 <- Not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use every as well. Iterate through the array, return true if value doesn't match value being searched so every continues, otherwise set ind and return false.

```
var getIndex = function(arr, match){
    var ind = -1;
    arr.every(function(val, index) {
      if (val === match){
          ind = index;
          return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
    return ind;
}

getIndex([1, 2, 3], 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
var index = 0;
var target = 'c';
var collection = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

function findIndex(){
  for(var val in collection) {
    if(collection[val] === target){
    return index;
  }
  index++;
 }
}

findIndex();
```